# SQL Server 2016 : WHERE statement evaluation

Tags: sql-server

I have something like this

```
declare @par int = null

select 
    count(distinct(t1.id))
from 
    my_table t1
left outer join 
    some_other t2 on t1.a = t2.b
where 
    @par is null or t2.c = @par
```

`@par` is null. With this `where` clause commented out, the query is fast, when uncommented - slow. Result is the same.

Why? Can't it spot that first part of or statement is true and not evaluate the second? How to best fix this (make it fast when @par is null).

SQL Server 2016

Comment: You mentioned in the comments that you have 20 such parameters. You need to read this article about this type of query. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
declare @par int = null

IF @par is null
BEGIN
    select count(distinct(t1.id))
    from my_table t1
END
ELSE BEGIN
    select count(distinct(t1.id))
    from my_table t1
         inner join some_other t2 on t1.a=t2.b
    where t2.c = @par
END
```

If you wish to use the left join approach then try below, it will prevent loading the join table when parameter has NULL value.

```
select count(distinct(t1.id))
from my_table t1
    left outer join some_other t2 on t1.a=t2.b
        and @par is not null    -- it will prevent loading the table when @par is null
where 
    @par is null or t2.c = @par
```

Comment: I believe inner join must exist in the first case too.

Comment: This woud probably work, but the problem is I have around 20 such parameters so not gonna work

Comment: @ren then I'd suggest you to use Dynamic SQL, if you're going to use that many optional parameters or use `OPTION (RECOMPILE);` hint.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas I'm using option recompile already. The answer by JaydipJ worked so no need for dynamic sql

Comment: @ren I have added second approach with your original left join method, this should work too.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `WHERE` WITH `AND ()`

```
select count(distinct(t1.id))
from my_table t1
left outer join some_other t2 on t1.a = t2.b
AND ( @par is null or t2.c = @par )
```

Comment: This answer seems interesting. Can you elaborate why this will have performance boost?

Comment: Yes this will may help to improve performance, if you are using left join table in where condition then this will behave like inner join, plus extra efforts required when there is where clause present in query this will also cause for performance issue

Comment: This is logically not the same as your original query, as this will give same count when @par has any value!

Comment: @JatinPatel Hm, indeed, damn, it's never easy